# Grails running jquery within a controller

Tags: jquery, grails, controller

Simple enough question but I can't find anything online to suggest how to do it...  I want the controller to run a jQuery check on a simple html table on screen before it runs the update action, but I cannot fathom how I'd do it, any ideas?

I tried running the check within a jQuery and then passing the value I needed through to the update action using a jquery post but that didn't work at all, when I checked the params it didn't look anything like it does when I run just a regular update...

The issue is I have a many to many relationship set which, currently, updates fine when adding to my list, or updating the values in the list, but the minute I need to remove one I run into difficulty, what I wanted to do was get the count of the html table (which contains my list of linked items) and then compare that to the database, if there are less in the table now than in the database I was going to run a basic delete from sql to clear out the now redundant linked items...

The only thing I can't work out is how to get this table count during the controller running, or call the controller and pass in this table number (well I can call the action and pass n the table number and id but this seems to lose all the other parameters), I had thought that `def formInstance = Form.get(id)` would get me all the params but that doesn't seem to do it at all :(

Alternatively is there another way to re-fill my params if I have the id to hand?

Any help much appreciated! :)

The Update controller looks like so: -

```
def update(Long id) {
        def formInstance = Form.get(id)
        int eventCount = formInstance.events.collect().count{id};

        if (!formInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'form.label', default: 'Form'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        formInstance.properties = params

        if (!formInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "edit", model: [formInstance: formInstance])
            return
        }

        int neweventCount = formInstance.events.collect().count{id};
        println(neweventCount)  


        flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'form.label', default: 'Form'), formInstance.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: formInstance.id)

    }
```

The params provided via the regular save button looks like so: -
    [id:3, formDesc:form 3, events[1].id:2, events[1]:[id:2], _action_update:Update, events[0].id:2, events[0]:[id:2], version:, action:index, controller:form]

But via a jQuery like so
    [id:14, myInt:1, action:update, controller:form]

To recap I think the problem is with the save but I can't work out how to correct it.  For example if I start with a "form" with 3 "events", and then remove one of these events from the table then save it the params look like such: -

```
[id:1, formDesc:form 112, events[1].id:1, events[1]:[id:1], _action_update:Update, events[0].id:1, events[0]:[id:1], version:, action:index, controller:form]
```

As you can see now only two events (0 and 1) are showing, and they are updated as I want, but the third event, which isn't showing in the params anymore, isn't being deleted from the link table as I want.

The only way round this I can think of is to get the table size from the screen then compare it to the number of events now being saved and do a manual SQL delete before or after saving, but I can't work out how to do this...

Comment: The simplest way I can think is to delete all relations and insert only the values marked by the user.
If you don't want to do that, you need to check instances that exists in the database and compare them with the values marked by the user. If you opt with second option, please post your view, to see how the values came to the `params`.

Comment: I thought about deleting all the values from the database hoping that the save function would just add them back in again, but when I try that it fails with an error reading `Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

Comment: Ok, so post your controller and view code, that will help to understand your issue.

Comment: Its not the view that's the problem its saving it, and the save is unmodified from a save created via the normal grails auto generate views and controllers but will post it above, will also include what the params look like when called via the normal button and via a jQuery script...

Comment: It's not the view, but the view says how the `params` come to controller...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being a moron, the params were already giving me a list of how many current events I now had, for some reason it didn't click that I could just derive the number of new params from that list I can then run a simple piece of sql off of that to delete all the now unneeded events! *slaps forehead*